# I am doing sign up with Google but not able to save it in my profile fragment

Tags: android, android-studio

Sign Up is an activity and I want to show name, email id and profile photo from Google account to show in my Profile fragment. What I want is to fetch all data and show it in my Profile fragment.

I am not able to show the data and how do I download that Photo URL and show it into my Profile Image view. I searched but I am not able to find solution.

```
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
String id = acct.getId().toString();
String name = acct.getGivenName().toString();
String emailId = acct.getEmail().toString();
Uri  photoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl();
MyProfileModelBean ab = new MyProfileModelBean();
ab.setId(id);
ab.setName(name);
ab.setEmail(emailId);
ab.setPhone("");
ab.setLocation("");
```

Comment: Refer this image downloading/caching library http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to do that

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

            Log.e(TAG, "display name: " + acct);

             personName = acct.getDisplayName();
            personPhotoUrl = String.valueOf(acct.getPhotoUrl());
             ggoleemail = acct.getEmail();
             googleid="G"+acct.getId();
            String baday= String.valueOf(acct.getAccount());


            Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName+googleid +baday+ ", email: " + ggoleemail
                    + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

            txtName.setText(personName);
            txtEmail.setText(email);
            Glide.with(getActivity()).load(personPhotoUrl)
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .crossFade()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(imgProfilePic);

            googleslogins();

            updateUI(true);
        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }
```